# each dynamic inputs array bidimensional

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem for each a dynamic inputs array from the first elements for validate

```
<div>
   <input name="item[0][name]"/>
   <textarea name="item[0][description]"></textarea>

   <input name="item[1][name]"/>
   <textarea name="item[1][description]"></textarea>

   <input name="item[2][name]"/>
   <textarea name="item[2][description]"></textarea>
</div>
```

The inputs and textareas are dynamics elements added, so I want make a each I use this code

```
$('input[name^="item"]').each(function() {
        console.log("hello");
});
```

but this return 6 hello in console, I need return in this example 3 hello or the count of item[], in reference that I have

```
item[0]
item[1]
item[2]
```

this because I need make a each for validate

```
item[0]
  item[0][name] ¿have a name?
  item[0][description] ¿have a description?

item[1]
  item[1][name] ¿have a name?
  item[1][description] ¿have a description?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Firstly your `input` are missing a closing `/>`. Also there's no way that the selector could loop 6 times given the code you've shown - not least of all because it would [match nothing](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/9b0atm7x/). Can you give us a working example of the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Use `input[name^=item]'` instead

Comment: Mohammad thanks but with name^=item I recieve 6 hello in the consoleLog

Comment: Rory McCrossan I fix this code example when I wrote the question but this is not  a problem :(

Comment: Because you have another input with name that start with `item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this

```
<div>
   <input name="item[0][name]" value="name"/>
   <textarea name="item[0][description]">description</textarea>

   <input name="item[1][name]" value="name"/>
   <textarea name="item[1][description]">description</textarea>

   <input name="item[2][name]" value="name"/>
   <textarea name="item[2][description]">description</textarea>
</div>
```

And javascript using jquery

```
var n = $( 'input[name^="item"]' ).length;

console.log(n);
for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    console.log(n);
  console.log($('input[name^="item['+i+'][name]"]').val());
  console.log($('textarea[name^="item['+i+'][description]"]').val());
}
```

Thanks to all!